# Where do I put model so that whenever could access them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, whenever

Simple and maybe stupid question. Just where? Simple generated model in /models doesn't work, and new class in /lib doesn't also... Just errors about undefined methods etc.

schedule.rb

```
every '* * * * *' do
runner 'UpdateDaysAgo.test'
end
```

model

```
class UpdateDaysAgo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def test
    UpdateDaysAgo.create(channel: "nil", title: "nil", game: "nil", avatar: "nil", created_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)
  end
end
```

error

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': private method `test' called for #<Class:0x00000004db7b40> (NoMethodError)
```

Whenever works fine, some cron jobs on `command` are good. But I have no idea about `models` and `runner` :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create [class method](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/):

```
class UpdateDaysAgo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.test
    UpdateDaysAgo.create(channel: "nil", title: "nil", game: "nil", avatar: "nil", created_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)
  end
end
```